# Simple node.js proxy by piping http server to http request

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

Trying to learn more about node.js by making a simple http proxy server. The use scenario is simple: user -> proxy -> server -> proxy -> user

The following code works until the last step. Couldn't find way to pipe connector's output back to the user.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var
    url = require('url'),
    http = require('http'),
    acceptor = http.createServer().listen(3128);

acceptor.on('request', function(request, response) {
    console.log('request ' + request.url);
    request.pause();
    var options = url.parse(request.url);
    options.headers = request.headers;
    options.method = request.method;
    options.agent = false;

    var connector = http.request(options);
    request.pipe(connector);
    request.resume();
//  connector.pipe(response); // doesn't work
//  connector.pipe(request); // doesn't work either
});
```

Using tcpflow I see the incoming request from the browser, then the outgoing proxy request, then the server response back to the proxy. Somehow i couldn't manage to retransmit the response back to the browser.

What is the proper way to implement this logic with pipes?

Answer (score 29):

you dont have to 'pause', just 'pipe' is ok

```
var connector = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.pipe(response, {end:true});//tell 'response' end=true
});
request.pipe(connector, {end:true});
```

http request will not finish until you tell it is 'end';

Comment: {end:true} is a nice suggestion. 10x.

Regarding pause, I still think it's better to use it. Imagine a user uploading a large file with HTTP POST. Why shall his file get buffered in the server's RAM while outgoing connection is under construction? And what if this outgoing connection is not possible for one reason or another?

Comment: FWIW, `{ end: true }` is no longer necessary with modern node - default is `true`, so you only need to pass options if you're disabling.

Answer (score 25):

OK. Got it.

UPDATE: NB! As reported in the comments, this example doesn't work anymore. Most probably due to the Streams2 API change (node 0.9+)

Piping back to the client has to happen inside connector's callback as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var
    url = require('url'),
    http = require('http'),
    acceptor = http.createServer().listen(3128);

acceptor.on('request', function(request, response) {
    console.log('request ' + request.url);
    request.pause();
    var options = url.parse(request.url);
    options.headers = request.headers;
    options.method = request.method;
    options.agent = false;

    var connector = http.request(options, function(serverResponse) {
            serverResponse.pause();
            response.writeHeader(serverResponse.statusCode, serverResponse.headers);
            serverResponse.pipe(response);
            serverResponse.resume();
    });
    request.pipe(connector);
    request.resume();
});
```

Comment: -1 because:  stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)

Comment: @rob, most probably this example doesn't work with the new Streams2 API. Streams2 were introduced as beta in node 0.9 and went stable in 0.10 branch. 0.10 was released march 2013 - months after this discussion. So, if you really want to be more constructive, instead of putting -1s, do adapt the example for the new API.

Comment: @NikolaiGorchilov The above example worked for me with node 0.10.13.  Only change I had to do is `response.writeHead` instead of `response.writeHeader`

Comment: could you please give advice for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684644/angularjs-expressjs-proxy-post-request-is-pending I will appreciate it very much :)

Comment: I took this and ran with it: https://gist.github.com/cmawhorter/a527a2350d5982559bb6 Hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: What is needed to enable websocket handling with this method? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5):

I used the examples from this post to proxy http/s requests. Faced with the problem that cookies were lost somewhere.

So to fix that you need to handle headers from the proxy response.

Below the working example:

```
const http = require('http');
const acceptor = http.createServer().listen(3128);

acceptor.on('request', function(request, response) {
  const req = service.request(options, function(res) {
      response.writeHead(res.statusCode, res.headers);
      return res.pipe(response, {end: true});
  });
  request.pipe(req, {end: true});
});
```

Comment: what is "response" inside the request callback?
Where is "request" coming from that you pipe from?