# Proxying Node Express route to another port on the same IP

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I want to route a request to my.ip:8000/foo to my.ip:8080/foo, to get around CORS limitations.

How can I do this in Express?

I found https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy which seems to proxy the entire port, not on the per path basis.

[node.js: route request to different port on same host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212178/node-js-route-request-to-different-port-on-same-host) talks about hosting multiple NODE apps but my second server isn't a node app. I just want to make a quick HTTP request on the same IP and return that as part of the first HTTP request from the client.

Comment: Why not just enable CORS on your server so the browser Javascript can contact your existing server directly?  If you're using some Unix, you can use iptable configuration to auto-forward from one port to another.

Comment: I'm serving react on 3000. Node server on 8000, erlang server on 8080. I need to enable CORS on the react app port 3000 OR do autoforwarding?