# how do I get data back from a nodejs http request?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

My purpose is beyond this simple request, but I am trying to make an http request and get the response back.

I have copied code from [nodejs.org http request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) to try to make an http request. I have modified the endpoint and the REST verb.

The code retrieves the page and writes this message to the console (of my express server output) and then hangs. It displays "No more data in response. End signal received." after displaying the html of the target page.

I get this hanging response through a web page and through postman.

The output reflects a STATUS 200 from the response. The linked page says that events occur in this order:
'socket'
'response'
'data'
'end' 
'close'

How do I stop the response from hanging? The end event is firing, do I have to trigger the close event myself?

Also, what is the preferred method for returning the response body? All of the examples go to console.log.

PLEASE DO NOT POST ANYTHING ABOUT ADDITIONAL LIBRARIES. I would like to make this work as it is advertised on the node.js page.

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'junto-peace.com',
      port: 80,
      path: '/story.html?article=peace',
      method: 'GET'
    };

let body = ''
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response. End signal received.');
  });
});

//EDIT: The code never reaches the next line:
console.log('outside of http.request. This line is never reached');

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(body);
req.end();
```

The output to the console shows the html of the page and the end of the output to the console reads: "No more data in response. End signal received."

i.e. this line is never reached: console.log('outside of http.request. This line is never reached');

EDIT: I added a console.log after the http.request code call. The code "hangs" or never gets there.
EDIT 2: As pointed out, this code runs fine from the command line by itself.

Comment: Are you trying to use this while responding to your own `http.Server`'s requests? If so, and you want to forward the contents of `story.html` to your own clients, one option is shown in [Simple node.js proxy by piping http server to http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472024/simple-node-js-proxy-by-piping-http-server-to-http-request)

Comment: "Returning" the response is the same as with an async method. I'm not sure what you mean by it's "hanging"; if I run this code from the command line it appears to work just fine, returning some HTML. It's not clear what you're trying to do by writing the results of the request to the request (which won't be filled with anything when `req.write` is called).

Comment: So how are you using it? That line *is* reached, it prints out first since it's the first output that'll get hit during normal execution.