# How to upload file between servers using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

- I have 2 servers (A and B) and 1 client (X).
- X can send a post request to A, containing a javascript `FormData` object (whose content is an in memory `File` object). Below is a piece of Angular code that successfully implement this:

```
   // Create a temporary file
   const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
   const file = new File([blob], reportName);

   // Create request payload containing the file
   const form = new FormData();
   form.append('file', file);

   // Send request
   this.http.post(url, form, { headers });
```

- Now that I want B to use the same api A provided, but `FormData`, `Blob` and `File` cannot be found in nodejs.

What would be the equivalent code for the above in nodejs? (I don't want to create a file somewhere in B and then upload)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple node.js proxy by piping http server to http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472024/simple-node-js-proxy-by-piping-http-server-to-http-request)

Comment: I found a way, using a custom readStream and writeStream to shuffle the file in memory, then using `form-data` module to achieve the work